# Is Kentor.AuthServices logging out correctly?

Tags: saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

I'm implementing a Service Provider proof-of-concept for SAML/SSO authentication using Kentor.AuthServices. The use case is a kiosk style application on which numerous different users may be authenticating one after another as they sign up for our service.

The problem I'm having is as follows: after logging out the user is unauthenticated as expected (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false). But when the next user goes to log in, the previously logged out user is re-authenticated without having to enter credentials. Is that expected behavior? If so, is there a way to prevent the behavior (other than manually dumping cookies)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that you are indeed terminating the local session on the SP. But when you try to log in again, the Idp still has an active session and automatically reauthenticates with that one.

To work around that you need to use Single Logout. AuthServices has support for that as of 0.17.0. To enable it, you need to have a service certificate configured (logout messages need to be signed). And of course your Idp must support it. Check for Logout endpoints in the Idp metadata.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will investigate.